# Twitter Trends places returns the same trend for different cities?

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to get hashtags for different german cities in python. So firstly I get the available trends:

```
twitter.trends.available(_woeid=23424829)
```

Then from this I get the trends for each place:

```
for trend in germany_trends:
    twitter.trends.place(_id=trend['woeid'])[0]['trends']
```

After that I filter the results to have to tweet with the highest `tweet_volume` for each city. Problem is: it's the same hashtag for each city. I get like 10 different cities from "trends available", but the hashtags are like 90% the same.

When I look into a map like this https://www.trendsmap.com/, I am wondering what I'm doing wrong. They have many seperate hashtags in all of those cities.

One example response, where you can see what I mean, the hashtags are nearly the same and the "best" hashtag is also the same:

```
"DE, Stuttgart": [
    {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23ISIS", 
        "query": "%23ISIS", 
        "tweet_volume": 21646, 
        "name": "#ISIS", 
        "promoted_content": null
    }, 
    {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Hans+Rosling%22", 
        "query": "%22Hans+Rosling%22", 
        "tweet_volume": 44855, 
        "name": "Hans Rosling", 
        "promoted_content": null
    }, 
    {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Betsy+DeVos%22", 
        "query": "%22Betsy+DeVos%22", 
        "tweet_volume": 664741, 
        "name": "Betsy DeVos", 
        "promoted_content": null
    }, 
    {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=Nioh", 
        "query": "Nioh", 
        "tweet_volume": 24160, 
        "name": "Nioh", 
        "promoted_content": null
    }, 
    {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23FCBWOB", 
        "query": "%23FCBWOB", 
        "tweet_volume": 14216, 
        "name": "#FCBWOB", 
        "promoted_content": null
    }, 
    {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23sid2017", 
        "query": "%23sid2017", 
        "tweet_volume": 28277, 
        "name": "#sid2017", 
        "promoted_content": null
    }
], 
"DE, Dresden": [
    {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Hans+Rosling%22", 
        "query": "%22Hans+Rosling%22", 
        "tweet_volume": 44855, 
        "name": "Hans Rosling", 
        "promoted_content": null
    }, 
    {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Betsy+DeVos%22", 
        "query": "%22Betsy+DeVos%22", 
        "tweet_volume": 664741, 
        "name": "Betsy DeVos", 
        "promoted_content": null
    }, 
    {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=Nioh", 
        "query": "Nioh", 
        "tweet_volume": 24160, 
        "name": "Nioh", 
        "promoted_content": null
    }, 
    {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23FCBWOB", 
        "query": "%23FCBWOB", 
        "tweet_volume": 14216, 
        "name": "#FCBWOB", 
        "promoted_content": null
    }, 
    {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23sid2017", 
        "query": "%23sid2017", 
        "tweet_volume": 28277, 
        "name": "#sid2017", 
        "promoted_content": null
    }
],
```

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: That I am getting the same "high voted" trends for every city in Germany. I want the trends which are specific for that city.

Comment: Wouldn't that be because every city has the same "high voted" trends?

Comment: I thought the tweet_volume is limited to one city, so I thought when filtering for the "high voted" trends I would get the best trends for each city... Guess the only way is to compare the arrays and delete non unique values

Comment: Exactly. What it can be happening is that city `X` and city `Y` both have the same "high voted" trends. That's why you get repeated values between cities.

Comment: Trendsmap may be using some algo on their side to filter tags. Website such as https://todaytagz.com that uses API to show trends sometime shows similar results for different cities.

Answer (score 2):

In https://www.trendsmap.com/ i am getting almost same tags for different cities.because most of the cities have same high trend.but still if you want unique high trends then you have to ignore the common high trend in most of the cities and have to choose the second highest [twitter trend for india](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YebSZ.jpg).
can take a dictionary of high trend in different cities and how many times it get repeated(count) `{'trend':count}` like `{'#sid2017':2,'#FCBWOB':2}` and leave the top 2-3 top trends from each city to get unique top trends for each city.

Answer (score 1):

> From [twitter dev](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place) site,
> You should send the request to this url

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json
```

And the criteria is
Requires authentication
Requests / 15-min window (user auth)=75
Requests / 15-min window (app auth)=75

A detailed information can be seen in the above link

**If there are same tags trending in 2 cities, the same tag will be returned**

Example, **at the time of US election, when check in each city, you will get tags related to `trump`. Likewise, if a hot topic is ongoing, you will get that tags only**